# equal_range for a list container

Tags: c++

I have a custom container that I am making that uses the STL list container as its internal structure. One of the items I am adding to this container is equal_range.

The code for my equal_range is here:

```
template <typename T> typename square_list<T>::iterator_pair square_list<T>::equal_range(key_type const& key) {
    auto range = std::equal_range(data_.begin(), data_.end(), key);
    for (square_list<T>::iterator it = range.first; it != range.second;) {
         if (range.first == data_.end() && range.second == data_.end())
            return std::make_pair(data_.end(), data_.end());
    ++it;
}

    return range;
}
```

I have some unit tests I am running against this implementation and everything is working, except for if the key value is not within the data structure. It's causing issues and .first and .second are not returning equal to the end of data_.

What do I need to change in order to have range.first and range.second be equal to the end of the `std::list<T> data_` if the key value is not within the list?

Here's the code for the unit test as well:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ut_equal_range) {
    vector<int> v{ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8 };
    square_list<char> sql(v.begin(), v.end());

    auto res = sql.equal_range(0);
    BOOST_CHECK(res.first == sql.cend());
    BOOST_CHECK(res.second == sql.cend());
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but why not just return `range`? It seems like `std::equal_range` does exactly what you are looking for already

Comment: Also, why did you put `++it` at the end of the for loop body instead of   inside the `for(...)`?

Comment: @mebob tried just returning range, and its not working. And I've been trying multiple methods of getting it to return what I want properly so the loop is attempt #5. I'm just experimenting currently.

Comment: Well, one thing to note: `std::equal_range` returns "a pair of iterators defining the wanted range, the first pointing to the first element that is not less than value and the second pointing to the first element greater than value." (cppreference.com). If `key` isn't in the range, then what will happen is it will return the size 0 range where the key WOULD be.

Comment: Note the information [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range)

Comment: So I should do some sort of comparison check where if the pair of iterators are element < value && !(value < element) then return a pair of iterators pointing to the end?

Comment: I'm going to assume that `data_` is always sorted. If so, then all you need to do is check for `range.first == range.second`, and if they are equal, `key` is not in `data_`.

Comment: @mebob awesome, that was what I needed. If you'd like, you can submit that as answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Done! And no problem. I tried to make the "official" answer as general as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::equal_range` will return a range of size 0 where `key` would be if it should fail to be in `data_`. So, if you would like to return a pair of iterators to `data_.end()` in that case, you should check if `range.first == range.second`, and return the pair of end iterators accordingly.

It's worth noting the restrictions on the input to `std::equal_range`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range

In short, the input to `equal_range` must be partitioned according to the key, meaning that some two sub-ranges must exist where one is composed of values all less than the key being searched for, and one composed of values all greater. A sorted range already has this guarantee.